# How do I query something specific in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, express, discord.js

I have had the other issue resolved with the Leaderboard API not refreshing properly. I now have another issue with express Querying where I am trying to search a specific Discord ID. Using quick.db for my database and reusing part of the express.js code below that works on my other project to search for Different Ban Evidences by ID.

`https://website.com/api/levelstats?id=DISCORDID`

When I put the Discord ID into the above URL. It should parse the URL and output the following result in an Object:
[image]

```js
app.get("/api/levelstats",  async function(request, response) {
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  if (!request.query.id) return response.send('null');
  let data;
  if (request.query.id !== 'all') data = await db.fetch('60Levelings', {
    target: request.query.id
  });
  else data = await db.fetch('60Levelings');
  if (!request.query.id !== 'all' && data) data.code = qs.parse(data.code).raw;
   response.send(JSON.stringify(data));
})
```

I've tried a different method which is params but to no success. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: So how is it not working? Error, wrong results, unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Hey there, it shows nothing or it just fetches all the leveling data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
app.get("/api/levelstats",  async function(request, response) {
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  if (!request.query.id) return response.send('null');
  let data;
  // change !== to != , maybe you can compare value only and ignore type data
  if (request.query.id != 'all') {
    // if request.query.id is not all, change type data request.query.id from string to int
    data = await db.fetch('60Levelings', {
      target: parseInt(request.query.id)
    });
    data.code = qs.parse(data.code).raw;
    response.send(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  else {
    data = await db.fetch('60Levelings');
  }
```